# Verify convergence of improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

Let $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^x-1}{\log{t}}dt$. I want to check if this improper integral is convergent or not (when $t>0$), and have tried out different measures, but couldn't find any thing that works. For example, I've tried finding $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert f(x,t) \leq g(t) \rvert, \forall x \in (0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^1 g(t)dt \lt \infty$ using $\lvert \log(t) \rvert \leq t$, but this doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Your integrand has a removable discontinuity at $t=1,$ so you need only examine the behavior of this improper integral near $t=0$. To do this, you should first show that $\int_0^{\delta}-\frac{1}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t$ converges for any $\delta\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$0< \frac{t^x-1}{\log(t)} < x$$

for $x>0$ and $0<t<1$. So that

$$f(x)\leq x\int_0^1 dt=x\ .$$

Comment: @MarkViola Maybe I'm missing something. The denominator goes to $-\infty$ and the numerator goes to $-1$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.